# cref on lslisting elements only translates to two questionmarks and the index of the element

Tags: listings, cleveref

I am rather new to working with LaTeX and so far I have not found the solution to following problem:

Using `\cref` or `\Cref` gives me the desired output whenever I use it with tables or figures. When I want to reference to a `\lslisting` element, the output is as follows:

Example reference in text:

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}
[language=Python,
caption=hello world code,
label=code:helloworld]
this is the code
\end{lstlisting}

This text references the first code snippet\cref{code:helloworld}
```

The rendered PDF shows "**??** 1" - assuming its the first lslisting element.

The label works as caption so I do not see what the problem with the reference is here.

I am using `cref` package as follows:

```
\usepackage[german, nameinlink, noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage[german]{babel}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{beramono}   % use a typewriter font which supports bold characters

\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Skriptverzeichnis}   % 
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Skriptverzeichnis}
\newcommand{\listoflolentryname}{\lstlistingname}
```

I kindly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % necessary for German and beramono
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{beramono}   % use a typewriter font which supports bold characters
\usepackage[german, nameinlink, noabbrev]{cleveref} % last package
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Skriptverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Skriptverzeichnis}
\newcommand{\listoflolentryname}{\lstlistingname}

\crefname{lstlisting}{skriptverzeichnis}{??}
\Crefname{lstlisting}{Skriptverzeichnis}{??}

\lstset{
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  language=Python,
  caption=hello world code,
  label=code:helloworld,%<--- note the comma
]
this is the code
\end{lstlisting}

\cref{code:helloworld}

\end{document}
```

Usually `cleveref` should be last, but `listings` doesn't cooperate.

Fix the `\crefname` labels.

[image]

The T1 encoding is essentially mandatory for German. And also for `beramono` that hasn't OT1 encoded fonts.

I also suggest to scale Bera Mono:

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{beramono}
```

The same as before with this change

[image]

Comment: Thanks to your resolution it works perfectly, i owe you!